# Regular expression to test a limited palette of possible values for a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need a regular expression to test if strings are in a specific palette of values for example string `dir` ca only be `ltr`, `rtl`, `lro`, `rlo`, or another example `bool` can be only `false`, `true`.

What regular expression, can I use to test a string like `dir` and `bool` against a limited set of values?

Comment: How about just checking to see if they're in an array of fixed values? Regular expressions aren't always the best tool for the job.

Comment: @JackManey For some people is a hammer ready to fix every nail, I caught a bit of the fever :D, now I understand the -1, I have a few fields and I wanted to define a dictionary of regexs, for every custom „type„ of field so I can write less code, but I guess is still better to treat every case, separately.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu - make a dict of sets instead. To spare coding, you can also write something like `set('ltr rtl lro rlo'.split())`

Comment: @eumiro I think you have a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like `'^(ltr|rtl|lro|rlo)$'` and `'^(true|false)$'`?

this can even be easily automated:

```
def make_re(args):
    args = (re.escape(arg) for arg in args) #if you want to escape special characters
    return re.compile('^({0})$'.format('|'.join(args)) )

boolre = make_re(('true','false'))
```

However, if you leave the line `args = (re.escape(arg) ...)` in there, then you really don't gain anything beyond what you could get using `if arg in myset: ...`.  The beauty of the unescaped version is that you still have at least some of the regex flexibility.

Comment: *this can even be easily automated* … until a pipe or other special character is included in the possible values…

Comment: @eumiro -- I actually prefer the unescaped version though as it would allow you to do more than you could do using a simple `set` (but forces the user to escape their characters).

Comment: if I do like this `^(false|true|)$` does it match an empty string? How about not being case sensitive?

Comment: To ignore case, do `re.compile( 'regexHERE', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: And yes, that will also match the empty string.  Note that `re.IGNORECASE` is where regular expressions start to become competative compared tho the `set` answer.

Answer (score 5):

Better than regular expressions, use lists or sets.

```
dir_choice = set(('ltr', 'rtl', 'lro', 'rlo'))

if dir in dir_choice:
    ...
```

(if your `dir_choice` is defined previously, the check is about six times faster than compiled regular expression of @IvanKoblik)

```
bool_choice = set(('true', 'false'))

if bool in bool_choice:
    ...
```

Comment: I agree with this, although why suggest a `list`? (+1)

Comment: @mgilson - If you already have a list and don't do this check frequently, then there is no need to create an extra set.

Comment: I've often wondered whether `__contains__` on very small lists/tuples could actually be faster than a `set`.  (`set` needs to hash and then check against collisions) compared to a simple string compare for a few elements ... I've never set up a benchmark though to test it.

Comment: @mgilson - depends on the match in the list. If the first element in the list (regardless list's length) matches, it is usually faster. Otherwise you have to **compare** with further elements.

Comment: @mgilson I guess on small sets the difference is negligible. But on big sets would be interesting, if there is not a new question that would be an interesting one

Comment: I thought that @mgilson was suggesting a dictionary (`dict((key,True) for key in dir_choice)`), as I thought it'd be more efficient for a large `dir_choice` (lists larger than 20).

Comment: @eumiro -- Yes, I realize that.  I'm wondering where the break even point is.  If you have a list of length 1, then you're saying it's probably faster than a set of length 1.  What about a list of length 2?  length 3?  At what length does the set do better than the list?  It's a difficult question though -- It could depend on whether you expect the string to be found, or whether you expect the key to be missing (sets will probably do better for smaller N if the typical case is a missing key).  I'd *guess* the breakeven point is somewhere around N=2 or 3, but it would be neat to measure ...

Answer (score 1):

To check if dir equals one of these strings you could use this:

```
re.match("^(ltr|rtl|lro|rlo)$", dir)
```

Another for bool:

```
re.match("^(false|true)$", bool)
```

Unless you follow better advice and use hash set for that purpose.